# Consulta entre 3 tablas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

tengo 3 tablas

- Campos tabla users: id,
- Campos tabla processes: id, user_id ("user_id" está relacionado con la tabla users)
- Campos tabla histories: id, processes_id ("processes_id" esta relacionado con la tabla processes)

users **tiene muchos** processes(procesos)

processes **tiene muchas** histories(historias)

histories **tiene un solo** processes(proceso)

lo que quiero hacer es:

> Traer los datos de **`history`** que estén relacionados con **`processes-user_id`** del usuario logueado

los procesos los traigo de la siguiente forma en el controlador:

```
$processes = Auth::user()->processes;
return view('processes.index', compact('processes'));
```

Pero con histories no he podido

Aquí el dd de la respuesta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me aparece al poner $data

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La estructura de tus tablas y la relación entre ellas no se entiende, ¿podrías editar y mostrarlas de mejor forma así como indicar que relación existe entre ellas?

Comment: Listo, dime si me hice entender esta vez

Comment: Relación 1 a 1 1:N?

Comment: listo, ya actualice

Comment: es que pueden haber muchos procesos, cada proceso puede tener muchas historias pero una historia solo puede tener un proceso que es el proceso con el que se creo dicha historia. no se si me hago entender

Comment: lo que necesito son todas las historias de todos los procesos del usuario logueado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero ocupas tener los modelos de tus 3 entidades respectivamente:

- User
- Process
- History

Modelos

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public function processes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Process::class);
    }
}

class Process extends Model 
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function histories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(History::class);
    }
}

class History extends Model 
{
    public function process()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Process::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora:

- Obtenemos el id del usuario logueado
- Cargamos del modelo History su relación process y como process es el método que nos da acceso a dciha tabla entonces podemos establecer un `where` para buscar la igualdad del `user_id` con la variable que almacena el id de la sesión actual

Propuesta

```
$user = auth()->user()->id;

$data = History::with(['process' => function($query) use($user){
    $query->where('user_id', $user);
}])->get();
```

Usamos `use` para pasar la variable `$user` al contexto de la función que la utilizará

Comment: lo de propuesta va en el controlador, no?

Comment: me aparece el siguiente error en la linea de $data: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']

Comment: Sería bueno comentarle que las arrow functions están disponibles en php 7.4

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107336/discussion-on-answer-by-betam-consulta-entre-3-tablas).

Comment: si funciona, solo era cache pero ya pude